# WCAG Text Spacing Plugin

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, plugins, accessibility

does anyone knows a plugin for chrome, ff to check WCAG 1.4.12 /Text Spacing (https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/?showtechniques=1412#text-spacing)

Thanks for you recommendations!

Comment: Hi Mila, this question isn't appropriate for the site. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. This is easy to test without a plugin, just do:- Line height (line spacing) to at least 1.5 times the font size; Spacing following paragraphs to at least 2 times the font size; Letter spacing (tracking) to at least 0.12 times the font size; Word spacing to at least 0.16 times the font size. See if your design still works if you set those things in your CSS and you are good to go if it does still work.

Answer (score 2):

A plugin or extension is probably overkill. Search the web for "text spacing bookmarklet"

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was never closed but shows up high on Google. This can be done as a bookmarklet. For example with this code:

```
javascript:(function(){var d=document,id='phltsbkmklt',el=d.getElementById(id),f=d.querySelectorAll('iframe'),i=0,l=f.length;if(el){function removeFromShadows(root){for(var el of root.querySelectorAll('*')){if(el.shadowRoot){el.shadowRoot.getElementById(id).remove();removeFromShadows(el.shadowRoot);}}}el.remove();if(l){for(i=0;i<l;i++){try{f[i].contentWindow.document.getElementById(id).remove();removeFromShadows(f[i].contentWindow.document);}catch(e){console.log(e)}}}removeFromShadows(d);}else{s=d.createElement('style');s.id=id;s.appendChild(d.createTextNode('*{line-height:1.5 !important;letter-spacing:0.12em !important;word-spacing:0.16em !important;}p{margin-bottom:2em !important;}'));function applyToShadows(root){for(var el of root.querySelectorAll('*')){if(el.shadowRoot){el.shadowRoot.appendChild(s.cloneNode(true));applyToShadows(el.shadowRoot);}}}d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);for(i=0;i<l;i++){try{f[i].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s.cloneNode(true));applyToShadows(f[i].contentWindow.document);}catch(e){console.log(e)}}applyToShadows(d);}})();
```

Comment: ^this proper and correct answer rescues the inappropriate question